# Access Attachemnt field in reusable workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, content-type, attachments, reusable-workflow

I have created one SPD **reusable workflow** based on my **custom content type**. As per my knowledge, we can't add attachment column in the content type.

Now in reusable workflow, we can only access columns which are part of my custom content type. But I want to access the value of default **attachment** field in the list.

How can I? Please help.